# Aws Location Service is accessible locally but not in another Aws Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-location-service

I am performing an operation on Amazon Service Location `geo:SearchPlaceIndexForText`.
It works properly in local env but as soon as I am performing the same operation in another Aws account I am getting this error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.location.model.AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/user-name 
is not authorized to perform:geo:SearchPlaceIndexForText  on resource: 
arn:aws:geo:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:place-index/HerePlaceIndex with an explicit
deny (Service: AmazonLocation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request
ID: 7df8b5bc-3033-4cb9-8fd0-sli98n7c9; Proxy: null)
```

Not sure why the same operation is working in locally and not in another Aws account.

The policy attached to the user-name  role is this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "geo:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

PS: My application is deployed in **AWS Account A** and I am trying to access the Location Service response from **Aws Account B** while calling the API from **Aws Account A**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Location Service is not allowing [Resource-based Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html).

Hence, in order to use Amazon Location Service API's we need the resource in the same Aws account.
Previously I was calling the Location Service API to retrieve the response from a different Aws account while sending the request from a different Aws account (Where the application is deployed).

Now I am utilizing the Location Service available in the same account where the application is deployed.